# How to create multiple sheets in csv file

Tags: excel

I would like to create multiple sheets in a csv file.When I have googled I haven't found any.May I know is it possible to create multiple sheets,If so do help me

Answer (score 1):

**This is not possible.** The .csv file is just a text file without any feature.
It's not linked to Excel.

If you want to use sheets, you must save your file in the Excel format ( .xls, .xlsx, .xlsm or thje variants)